# Wordpress Custom CSS, horizontal scroll bar at the bottomf of the page but why?

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, scrollbar

I have noticed that [this page](http://www.shaunhillphotography.co.uk/portraits/) is displaying a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the page but I cannot understand why or how to fix it. It's happening on one of the other pages too, but none of the others.

Please can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the issue immediately. BUt my suggestion for a quick fix would be adding this to #wrapper.

```
#wrapper{overflow: hidden;}
```

It looks like the content within wrapper is somehow larger than wrapper is? I can't see how, it appears to be the same size.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell there isn't anything that is breaking the width of the child container you can fix it by adding `overflow:hidden` on `#container`

Answer (score 0):

You're using cufon which dynamically converts text into images in order to display special fonts that aren't typically supported. This is stretching out the area inside the div. My advice would be to not use cufon, and instead use fonts that are supported by the web. Alternatively, you can listen to what others have said about hacking a hack by changing the overflow to hidden.

Comment: That is a great answer, how do I make the overflow hidden?